# Unable to make the content of showDialog scrollable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I am trying to implement a `TextField` in a `showDialog`. I have a `CustomShowDialog` widget created for this purpose.

**Issue Faced**

When I click on the `TextField`, the keyboard appears which covers up the `TextField`. When I try to wrap the `CustomDialog` with `SingleChildScrollView`, I am getting the following error:

**RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#be9c1 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE**

**Code**

*custom_dialog.dart*

```
class CustomDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDialog({
    Key? key,
    required this.svgAssetPath,
    required this.title,
    required this.message,
    required this.auxWidget,
    required this.actionWidget,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String svgAssetPath;
  final String title;
  final String message;
  final Widget auxWidget;
  final Widget actionWidget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: (22 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
          right: (22 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
          bottom: (22 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
          top: (150 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: 100.w,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular((24 / Dimensions.designWidth).w)),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: (22 / Dimensions.designWidth).w),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            svgAssetPath,
                            width: (147 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
                            height: (147 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
                          ),
                          const SizeBox(height: 40),
                          Text(
                            title,
                            style: TextStyles.primaryBold.copyWith(
                              color: const Color(0xFF252525),
                              fontSize: (24 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizeBox(height: 20),
                          Text(
                            message,
                            style: TextStyles.primaryMedium.copyWith(
                              color: const Color(0xFF252525),
                              fontSize: (16 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                          auxWidget,
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  actionWidget,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*view.dart*

```
SolidButton(
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(34, 97, 105, 0.17),
              fontColor: AppColors.primary,
              onTap: () {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    final ShowButtonBloc showButtonBloc =
                        context.read<ShowButtonBloc>();
                    return CustomDialog(
                      svgAssetPath: ImageConstants.warning,
                      title: "Reject Reason",
                      message:
                          "Please provide the reason for rejection below",
                      auxWidget: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const SizeBox(height: 20),
                          Text(
                            "Remarks",
                            style: TextStyles.primaryMedium.copyWith(
                              color: const Color(0xFF636363),
                              fontSize: (16 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizeBox(height: 10),
                          BlocBuilder<ShowButtonBloc, ShowButtonState>(
                            builder: (context, state) {
                              return CustomTextField(
                                controller: _reasonController,
                                bottomPadding:
                                    (16 / Dimensions.designWidth).w,
                                minLines: 3,
                                maxLines: 5,
                                maxLength: 200,
                                onChanged: (p0) {
                                  if (p0.length >= 20) {
                                    isReasonValid = true;
                                  } else {
                                    isReasonValid = false;
                                  }
                                  showButtonBloc.add(
                                    ShowButtonEvent(show: isReasonValid),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      actionWidget:
                          BlocBuilder<ShowButtonBloc, ShowButtonState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          if (isReasonValid) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                GradientButton(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  text: "Proceed",
                                ),
                                const SizeBox(height: 20),
                              ],
                            );
                          } else {
                            return const SizeBox();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              text: "Reject",
            ),
```

**Request**

What is causing the error mentioned above, and how do I implement a scrollable dialog such that the `TextField` is not hidden by the keyboard.

**Images**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fix: When you are using SingleChildScrollView, In that case, you are not allowed to use Expanded Widget. So please make that widget of specific height (and remove Expanded Widget) and then your issue will be resolved

Comment: I don't want to make the content of the `CustomDialog` scrollable, instead I want to be able to scroll the entire part of the screen when the dialog appears. I have not used `Expanded` anywhere inside `showDialog()`.

Comment: The problem is that the popup dialog is out of the scroll control of the main page, since it's not part of the same layout.  Perhaps if your dialog contained its own scaffold?  Dunno.

Comment: add this margin: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets in your dialog.